# Pattern matching against a type with only one constructor

Tags: haskell, types, constructor, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

If I pattern-match against an expression whose type has only one constructor, will that still force the runtime to evaluate the expression to WHNF?

---

I did an experiment that seems to indicate it doesn't evaluate:

```
Prelude> data Test = Test Int Int
Prelude> let errorpr () = error "Fail"
Prelude> let makeTest f = let (x,y) = f () in Test x y
Prelude> let x = makeTest errorpr
Prelude> let Test z1 z2 = x
Prelude> :sprint z1
z1 = _
Prelude> :sprint z2
z2 = _
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

I would have expected to either get an error or :sprint x to yield

```
x = Test _ _
```

but it didn't.

---

Apparently I didn't understand how "let" works.  See the answers below

Comment: Sorry it's confusing, the type I'm pattern-matching against is (Int, Int)

Answer (score 6):

```
Prelude> let x = makeTest errorpr
Prelude> let Test z1 z2 = x
```

The last line does not force the evaluation of anything: patterns within `let` are (implicitly) *lazy patterns* (aka irrefutable patterns). Try instead

```
Prelude> let x = makeTest errorpr
Prelude> case x of Test z1 z2 -> "hello!"
Prelude> :sprint x
```

and you should observe something like `Test _ _`, since patterns in `case` are not lazy ones. By comparison,

```
Prelude> let x = makeTest errorpr
Prelude> case x of ~(Test z1 z2) -> "hello!"   -- lazy pattern!
Prelude> :sprint x
```

should print just `_`, like when using `let`.

The above holds for `data` types. Instead, `newtype`s do not lift the internal type, but directly use the same representation. That is, `newtype` value construction and pattern-matching are *no-ops* at runtime: they are roughly erased by the compiler after type checking.

Answer (score 3):

(As the possibility of having many constructors was mentioned, I presumed that the question referred to a `data` type.  The answer is different if a `newtype` is used.  See the comments.)

Yes, it will.  Try for example:

```
data T = C Int                                                                  

unT (C n) = 42                                                                  

main = print $ unT undefined
```

and you will get an undefined exception, instead of 42.

But of course it depends on the pattern.  If you replace the definition of `unT` with:

```
unT ~(C n) = 42
```

using a lazy pattern, the result will be 42.  Also, note that a constructor pattern used in a `let` expression (e.g., `let (C n) = something` is also equivalent to a lazy pattern.

---

Regarding the rest of your question, `makeTest` generates a `Test` value whose parameters are not used.  If they had been used, you'd get an error of course (e.g., had you used `print` instead of `:sprint`).  The reason why `x` does not give you `Test _ _` is because the `let` expression in line 5 corresponds to a lazy pattern (section 3.12 in the Haskell 98 Report).  It's as if you had written `let ~(Test z1 z2) = x`.  Therefore, `x` is never evaluated.

Comment: To add to this: if this is not desirable behavior, `newtype` does not behave this way.

Comment: I did a different experiment and got the opposite result.  Can you explain why?  See my updated question.

Comment: Note that this is different for `newtype`. A newtype doesn't really exist at runtime, so wrapping and unwrapping does not force evaluation to WHNF. If you write `newtype T = C Int`, then the program prints 42.

Comment: `case undefined of {A _ -> ()} == ()` if `A` is a `newtype` because pattern matching on a `newtype` does nothing; it is the same as writing `case undefined of {_ -> ()}`. If `A` is a datatype, then `case undefined of {A _ -> ()} == undefined` because the *value* `A x` is distinct from `x`.